# .NET ThreadPool tasks queued while pool not exhausted

Tags: asp.net, .net, threadpool, dotnet-httpclient

**Question**

What can cause tasks to be queued in Thread Pool while there are plenty threads still available in pool?

**Explanation**

Our actual code is too big to post, but here is best approximation:

```
long running loop
{
  create Task 1
  {
    HTTP Post request (async)
    Wait
  } 
  create Task 2
  {
    HTTP Post request (async)
    Wait
  } 
  Wait for Tasks 1 & 2
}
```

The issue is that these HTTP requests which usually take 110-120 ms sometimes take up to 800-1100 ms.

**Before you ask:**

- Verified no delays on server side
- Verified no delays on network layer (tcpdump + wireshark). If we have such delays, there are pauses between requests, TCP level turn-around fits in 100ms

**Important info:**

We run it on Linux.
This happens only when we run the service in container on k8s or docker.
If we move it outside container it works just fine.

**How do we know it's not ThreadPool starvation?**

We have added logging values returned by `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` and we have values of 32k and 4k for available threads.

**How do we know the tasks are queued?**

we run `dotnet-counters` tool and we see queue sizes up to 5 in same second when issue occurs.

**Side notes:**

- we control the network, we are 99.999% sure it not it (because you can never be sure...)
- process is not CPU throttled
- the process usually have 25 - 30 threads in total at given time
- when running on k8s/docker we tried both container and host network - no change.

**HttpClient notes**:

- We are using this HTTP client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0
- Client instances are created before we launch the loop.
- These are HTTP, not HTTPS requests
- URLs are always the same per task, server is given as IP, like this `http://1.2.3.4/targetfortaskX`

Generally - using tcpdump and wireshark we observe two TCP streams to be opened and living through whole execution and all requests made are assigned to one of these two streams with `keep-alive`. So no delays on DNS, TCP SYN or source port exhaustion.

Comment: Could you please post [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `This happens only when we run the service in container on k8s or docker. If we move it outside container it works just fine.` so it *is* a networking problem, inside the cluster or container. Network IO doesn't use the CPU and hence threadpool threads. There are parts of the call though that *do* require CPU, like looking up in-memory tables. On top of that, Linux IO isn't fully asynchronous, the way Windows is (on Windows all IO is asynchronous, with synch calls getting emulated).

Comment: How are the HTTP requests executed? If you use the same HttpClient, as you should, you avoid the DNS resolution overhead on every call. The HttpClient caches and reuses the socket connections to every target machine. If you use a new HttpClient instance every time, you have to resolve the domain name to an IP and finally, a socket, on every call.

Comment: What does `Wait` mean? Is this an explicit `await Task.Delay()` to emulate throttling? Or a `Thread.Sleep()` that puts a threadpool thread to sleep?

Comment: @PeterCsala, we are working on trying to reproduce it in minimal synthetic example.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 

See edit for clarification on HttpClient usage.

`Wait` means wait on async task to be finished.
We tried both `client.PostAsync(...).Result` and `Task.Wait) - no difference.

On loop level we have `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());` to wait for both Task 1 & 2 finish.

We are adding no extra delays here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `so it is a networking problem`. That was our first suspect and we are following this lead too. As mentioned above - for now, the only correlation we found is between delays and ThreadPool queue.

So, this question is to follow the ThreadPool lead - why we have tasks queued if the pool is not exhausted?

What are the factors that can contribute to queuing?

Comment: Inefficient application code. If you have to resolve the DNS address on every call, and that gets delayed, your calls get delayed. If `Wait` means `Thread.Sleep()`, the threadpool will get exhausted. `the only correlation` as data scientists say, correlation doesn't mean causation. You *will* see queueing if you have a network problem, because the network calls will get stuck.

Comment: `We tried both client.PostAsync(...).Result and Task.Wait) - no difference.` you're explicitly blocking the threadpool thread. It's the same with `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`. The whole point of async operations is to use `await` to await asynchronous operations to complete without blocking the calling thread

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 

`If you have to resolve the DNS address` - we don't please read last section of question post

`If Wait means Thread.Sleep()` - see comment above what `Wait` means. There is also section in post that explains we don't think it's pool exhaustion

Comment: I've read the comments and they prove the problem starts from the code, blocking operations that shouldn't be blocked. It makes little sense trying to find why threads are blocked when the application explicitly blocks those background threads. `.Wait` is the equivalent of `Thread.Sleep()` - it blocks the threadpool thread until the asynchronous operation completes. Either Visual Studio or Resharper is already complaining about this.

Comment: BTW you didn't post the output of `dotnet-counters`. It's quite likely the output was misinterpreted, just as awaiting and blocking were. Having 32K threads doesn't mean you have 32K cores to run them. If you only have 4 cores that are busy-waiting for an operation to complete, all other requests will have to wait. Blocking calls don't evict the current thread from a core immediately because rescheduling can take a lot of time. That's why most blocking operations start with busy-waiting. The incorrect use of `.Wait()` *causes* the queuing

Comment: This isn't an issue if async operations are used properly. With `await client.GetStringAsync()`, the runtime hands an async network operation to the OS and immediately releases the threadpool thread to serve other tasks. When the network operation completes, the OS notifies the runtime which restores the original execution (or rather, synchronization) context and resumes after `await`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos

Can you confirm the meaning of the `threadpool-queue-length` well known counter? Is it "threads in pool waiting for OS level scheduling" or "queue of submitted tasks that are waiting for thread from pool to be assigned"?

Comment: And if all 4 cores are busy spinwaiting, tasks will start queueing even if there are 30K threads. What's the CPU usage per core when tasks start queueing?